# punctuation removal with python Regular expression

Tags: python

```
import re
def removePunctuation(text):
    """Removes punctuation, changes to lower case, and strips leading and trailing spaces.

    Note:
        Only spaces, letters, and numbers should be retained.  Other characters should ​be
        eliminated (e.g. it's becomes its).  Leading and trailing spaces should be removed after
        punctuation is removed.
​
    Args:
        text (str): A string.
​
    Returns:
        str: The cleaned up string.
    """
    a=0
    while(a==0):
        if(text[0]==' '):
            text=text[1:]
        else:
            a=1
    while(a==1):
        if(text[-1]==' '):
            text=text[0:-1]
        else:
            a=0
    text=re.sub('[A-Z]', '[a-z]', text)
    return re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '', text)
print removePunctuation('Hi, you!')
print removePunctuation(' No under_score!')
```

Result:

```
azi you
azo underscore
```

Frist, I delete the space at the begin and the end of the string.
Then, make the string lower case.
Finally, remove all that are not a-z and numbers.

The expected result should be

```
hi you
no underscore
```

I don't know why I got "az" at the front of the string and the first character is missing...

Comment: Is this part of a course assignment? You also don't need a regex, see my answer in the dupe

Comment: you know, there's something like `text.strip()`? `if` and `while` are no functions, so why the parens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your problem

```
text=re.sub('[A-Z]', '[a-z]', text)
```

Change it to

```
text=text.lower()
```